# Regex to match lines in-between two specific lines, in Python

Tags: python, regex, newline

I am trying to use regex to parse out some lines from text read in from a file. I know this could be done by reading in the file, line-by-line, but I like the elegance in capturing all the relevant bits of info in a single regex match.

The example file contents:

```
---
title: a title
layout: page
---

here's some text
================

this will be blog post content.
```

I am trying to produce a regex match that will return 2 groups: the data in-between the "---" lines, and all of the data after the 2nd "---" line. Here is the regex string I have come up with, and I am having an issue with it:

```
re.match('---\n(.*?)\n---\n(.*)', content, re.S)
```

This seems to work well, except when dealing with unix vs windows line-endings. Is there a way to allow this regex to match a \r if it's present, too? It works with the unix, which is just `\n` I believe.

Also, if you think this regex could be improved, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence `(\r\n|\r|\n)` will match all 'normal' line endings (Windows, old Mac, and *nix, respectively).

Answer (score 4):

The end of line markers are considered whitespace so you can use the construct `\s+` to match the end of line (and other whitespace) that is platform independent.

Comment: That's bad because it'll match a one-liner `--- title: a title layout: page --- here's some text ================`, and the OP said multiple lines.

Comment: @smci Not necessarily. It depends on what the OP needs. This matches multiple lines.

Comment: I know it matches multiple lines, what I said was it also unwantedly matches single lines, which was not what the OP asked for. Whereas the `(\r\n|\r|\n)` suggested by Porges is safer. Using `\s+` as a catchall is too loose.

Comment: @smci What I am saying is that maybe the OP doesn't care that it's too loose? Maybe it's OK that it also matches one line. The OP didn't specify that it should not, so how do you know it's unwanted? Also, the input seems to be in a well defined format that won't every have that form. So, in other words, your suggestion is out of scope with regards to the spec. Over-engineered. ;-)